# Identify $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3, 5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm asked to identify $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3, 5)$.

I think it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2+3)$, but what next, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you determine the elements exactly?

Comment: You've made a good start.  The next step depends on your background.  As a hint, is $x^2 + 3$ reducible over $\mathbb Z_5$?

Comment: Yes, good start, now always remember (as a practical rule) that, for polynomials of degree $\leq 3$, one has $$\mbox{irrreducible}\Longleftrightarrow \mbox{no root}$$ and find if it has a root by substitution.

Comment: @vadim123, $ \{ax+b|a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_5\} $?

Comment: It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_5}[\sqrt{3}]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3, 5)$ $\cong$ $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2+3)$. Now $x^2+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ hence this will be a field of order $25$. Precisely the elements are looks like $\{ax+b+\langle x^2+3\rangle|a,b \in  \mathbb{Z}_5\}$.